# Zend Cache APC error Failed saving metadata to metadataCache

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching, apc

I seems to be stuck trying to get APC to work with Zend Cache from a CLI.

I know APC is installed ( can see it in infophp();

I can dump the code and see that the APC value is being pulled in from a config file.

But when I run the command on the command line:
/usr/bin/php -c /var/www/html/php.ini /var/www/html/public/index.php cronhalfhourly

I get the error:
PHP Notice:  Failed saving metadata to metadataCache in /ebs1/www/html/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php on line 839

When I use "File" instead of APC, it works fine, fiels are written to  the cache dir. When it's APC, no files are written tot he cache dir, as one would expect.

Here's my code:

```
protected function _initCache() {

    $strings_config = Zend_Registry::get('strings_config');

    $frontendOptions = array(
            'lifetime' => 7200,
            'automatic_serialization' => true
            );

    $backendOptions  = array(
            'cache_dir'=> $strings_config->tablemetadatacachepath
            );



    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core',
                                                             $strings_config->backendcache,
                                                             $frontendOptions,
                                                             $backendOptions);

    // Next, set the cache to be used with all table objects        
    Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache($cache);
Zend_Registry::set('cache',$cache);
```

}

I'm stuck, any ideas?

Comment: Are directory permissions ok?

Comment: If you do `php -m` is APC in the list? (PHP CLI uses a different php.ini to Apache)

Comment: Yes, directory perms are 777, but have also tried 755. Should have mentioned that earlier. And yes, Apc shows in the list. I've even tried adding Apc.enable=1 to the php.ini and it throws the "Apc already enabled" error.

Comment: And I THOUGHT I had added in the php.ini apc.enable_cli=1, but apparently I did not. Adding this fixes the problem,

Comment: I get this even with the FILE option and the permissions are ok.